# pandas: find rows remaining after `drop_duplicates`?

Tags: pandas

Is there an efficient way in pandas to do the following query?

I'd like to find all rows that have a date of `22-08` and an ID, that don't appear with the date `21-08` and the same ID.

So in this dataframe, I'd like to query for `date: 22-08` and retrieve just the row with ID 125:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
   {"id": 123, "date": "21-08", "price": 3000, "desc": "bar"},
   {"id": 124, "date": "21-08", "price": 7000, "desc": "foo"},
   {"id": 123, "date": "22-08", "price": 3000, "desc": "bar"},
   {"id": 124, "date": "22-08", "price": 7000, "desc": "foobar"},
   {"id": 125, "date": "22-08", "price": 4000, "desc": "baz"}
])
```

The tricky bit is that I want to ignore rows where other information has changed, like row `124`. It's only the ID number and date I care about. So I think the best way will be to:

- run `drop_duplicates`, looking at a subset of ID and date
- find the rows remaining after the `drop_duplicates` is run.

If so, is there an efficient way to do that?

Comment: `df.loc[(~df['ID'].duplicated) & df['date'].eq('22-08')]`?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is:

```
aux = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'date'])
aux[(aux['date'] == '22-08') & 
    (~aux['id'].isin(aux[aux['date'] == '21-08']['id']))]
```

Or maybe more efficiently:

```
df[(df['date'].eq('22-08')) & (~df['id'].isin(df.loc[df['date'].eq('21-08'),'id']))]
```

Output:

```
    id   date  price desc
4  125  22-08   4000  baz
```

Comment: You don't need the `drop_duplicates`, no?

Comment: You are right, @mozway: Have just updated my solution meanwhile. Thanks!

Comment: avoid chaining index, it's better do `df.loc[boolean_series, 'id']` than `df[boolean_series]['id']`.

Comment: Thanks, @QuangHoang, for your comment! Is there some reason for that?

Comment: FYR: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: Thanks, @QuangHoang! Always learning!